# Getting __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance' with CreateView of Django

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

## Some details:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/user/create
Django Version: 1.5.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: ____init____() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'
Exception Location: /place/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py in get_form, line 35
Python Executable: /place/venv/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
```

## views.py

```
class UserCreateView(CreateView):
    model = models.User
    form_class = forms.UserForm
```

## urls.py

```
url(r'^user/create$', UserCreateView.as_view(), name='user_create'),
```

## forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.Form):
    GROUP_CHOICES = [(-1, '[Choose]')]
    GROUP_CHOICES += [(group.id, group.name.capitalize()) for group in auth.models.Group.objects.all()]

    email = forms.EmailField(
        label='Email',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email'})
    )
    first_name = forms.CharField(
        label='First Name',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'First Name'})
    )
    last_name = forms.CharField(
        label='Last Name',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Last Name'})
    )
    password = forms.CharField(
        label='Password',
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'})
    )
    password_validation = forms.CharField(
        label='Repeat Password',
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Repeat Password'})
    )
    mobile_number = forms.CharField(
        label='Mobile Number',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Mobile Number'})
    )
    office_number = forms.CharField(
        label='Office Number',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Office Number'})
    )
    group = forms.ChoiceField(
        label='Group',
        choices=GROUP_CHOICES
    )

    def clean_password_validation(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['password'] == self.cleaned_data['password_validation']:
            return self.cleaned_data['password_validation']
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords don\'t match')

    def clean_group(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['group'] != -1:
            return self.cleaned_data['group']
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Please, choose a group')
```

## models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(auth.models.User)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    office_number = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Answer (score 107, accepted):

I suspect class `UserForm` should be model form. You may want to change fields, but it should be derived from `ModelForm.

So change form definition to

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = User
       fields = [...] # list of fields you want from model

   #or define fields that you want.
   ....
```

Comment: Is it not possible to make a form without the models in CreateView?

Comment: @tilaprimera: I don't think this is possible in `CreateView`, but you can use `FormView` and manually override `form_valid()`.

Comment: Year it is worked.  class UserForm(forms.ModelForm) replace forms.Form :)

Answer (score 2):

I override __init__() method incorrectly, without initial arguments, as show below

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    def __init__(self):
        super(CaseForm, self).__init__()
        ...
```

And get this error as result

> TypeError at /case/create
>
> __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'initial'

To fix it, I set arguments to __init__() and pass them when call super class __init__(), see result below

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CaseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

forms.py
Defines Fields in Square Brackets like fields=['field 1', 'field 2',...]

```
class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):        
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['fname','lname','email','address','city','state','zip','username','password','age','mobile','phone']
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar error I got when trying to save a form to a database. "Report() got an unexpected keyword argument 'summary'"

The problem was that the field names in models.py and forms.py didn't match.

In the class Report in models.py the name of the field was "summary_input", but in forms.py it was named "summary", so I changed the variable name in forms to match the one in models.

```
# models.py
class Report(models.Model):
    summary_input = models.TextField()

# forms.py
class ReportForm(forms.Form):
    summary = forms.CharField(widget=forms.widgets.Textarea)
    # changed to 
    # summary_input = forms.CharField(widget=forms.widgets.Textarea)
```